# Custom style property - XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

Is it possible to create a custom property and bind it to some value in code behind.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" x:Key="ContainerStyle">
        <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="{Binding IsEditable, Mode=TwoWay}" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EditableTextBox}" />
            </Trigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

What I want to do is swap between the NotEditableText and EditableText templates depending on the value of IsEditable that is set in the PersonViewModel class. But I don't really how to bind everything together.

**SOLUTION**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" x:Key="ContainerStyle">
        <Setter Property="ViewModel:PersonViewModel.IsEditable" Value="{Binding IsEditable, Mode=TwoWay}" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ViewModel:PersonViewModel.IsEditable" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EditableText}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you want to do? Your xaml doesn't help at all and i don't understand your question. Can you bind to custom dependency properties? Of course. Can you use binding in code? Of course. Can i add dependency properties to existing classes? Kind of, search for attached properties. I can keep on guessing but ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but your property must be [DependancyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx). Otherwise it will not respond to Binding events. Adding DependancyProperty is quite easy.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSpinningProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "IsSpinning", typeof(Boolean),
    );

public bool IsSpinning
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSpinningProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsSpinningProperty, value); }
}
```

Once you create a property like this, you can use it in Style.Triggers as you described in your scenario.
Your property must be present in the class that is used in your `TargetType="{x:Type MyType}"`.

Comment: I still have an error with the Trigger:

    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="True">

Cannot find the Style Property 'IsEditable' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem'.

Comment: The reason for this is because the class TreeViewItem does not have IsEditable property. Have you inherited this class? Your code points to a type of System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem, and the error you get is logical.

Comment: I want to set all style in XAML, then by just setting true or false on the IsEditable property, XAML will pick the proper template. Is it possible to achieve this ?

Comment: Well, you're trying to bind to a non-existant property. The property you are binding, must exists in the type defined in `TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"`. So it can be done, yes, but I think you're not exactly asking the right question, or we're missing some code. Where did you put your `IsEditable` property? In which class?

Comment: I get the property now if I use the proper class.

Comment: The IsEditable property is in my PersonViewModel. How can I trigger the treeviewitem to become a textbox or textblock based on that property within XAML. I can paste more code, but it might be overwhelming...

Comment: Paste more code, just trim the unnecessary lines. Paste only relevant code, class where your property is defined, your xaml usage, and probably a clear idea of what you want bound.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just set this style via code, you can use:

```
 Style containerStyle = (Style)FindResource("ContainerStyle");
 this.someTreeView.Items[0].Style = containerStyle;
```